# Using read to get user input and assigning that to a variable later on causes it to lose its case

Tags: bash, shell, capitalization

Let's say I have a directory, /user/Jack/PROJECT1/tool1.

I'm trying to check to see if this directory exists in my shell script.

Here's the snippet of code I'm dealing with:

```
echo -e "Enter complete path: "
read verifydir
if [ ! -d $verifydir ] 
then
  echo -e $verifydir "is not a valid directory"
else
  mydir=$verifydir
fi
exedir="$mydir/tool1"
pgmname=$exedir"/mytool.exe"
if [ ! -f "$pgmname" ]
then
echo -e $pgmname "not found."
exit -l
fi
```

My problem is that while the first check (the existence of the directory) works, the second check (for pgmname) is not finding the program if the directory name is in all caps (like PROJECT1). It's converting the PROJECT1 to project1. How can I fix this?

Comment: if this is bash, why spaces while doing variable assignment,  `mydir = $verdir` should be `mydir=$verdir`, `if [ ! -f "pgmname" ]` should be `if [ ! -f "$pgmname" ]`, pgmname = $exedir"/mytool.exe"` should be `pgmname="$exedir"/mytool.exe`

Comment: That's what it actually is, but it's on my dev machine and I don't have internet there, so I had to rewrite it here and I have the habit of using spaces from other languages, sorry! I'll fix it.

Comment: Please provide the exact source code.

Comment: Put `set -x` before this section of the script, so bash will print the equivalent of the command it's executing; that should clarify what's going on to cause the problem.

Comment: You don't have anything in your code which would change captialization. Can you recreate the effect on the command line? You are on Linux, aren't you?

Comment: @user1934428 You're right-- there wasn't anything in the code posted that did it. It was a relatively large script, and I can't copy and paste the whole thing, but I found a typeset -l on one of the variables I was using that caused this. Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved the issue. Previously in the code, someone set typeset -l pgmname .

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is elsewhere, i.e. in next line:

```
if [ ! -f "pgmname" ]
```

This should be

```
if [ ! -f "$pgmname" ]
```

Once this is fixed, we can talk further.

Comment: Oops, I see P... already pointed this out. Sorry.

Comment: This should have been a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `ls`

```
if [[ $(ls $pgmname) ]]
```

Please elaborate on what your problem is